# okhttp3 with Retrofit where is the cached file on the phone? Unable to see it inside the Application directory

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

okhttp3 with Retrofit where is the cached file on the phone? Unable to see it inside the Application directory here is my code:
I am sending the request in Android and the results are also coming out fine but where is it being cached??

```
CACHE_SIZE_BYTES also defined 10 mb
...some code
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
builder.cache(new Cache(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(),CACHE_SIZE_BYTES));
OkHttpClient client = builder.build().client(client);
final Retrofit retrofitlogin=new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(GlobalROOT_URL)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
..rest of the code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OkHttp cache files aren't meant to be accessed by other applications, the format isn't documented or considered a public API, and concurrent access could cause problems.

But if you log the cache directory it will tell the directory you are storing files in

```
Log.w("WARN", getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().toString())
12-22 08:11:22.071 16936-16936/? W/WARN: /data/user/0/com.squareup.okhttptestapp/cache
```